# How can I delete two column (attribute) at a time from one table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I delete two column (attribute) at a time from one table in mysql?

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` DROP COLUMN `column1`, DROP COLUMN `column2`
```

Comment: Assuming that's legal syntax -- I don't think it is in MS SQL Server -- it certainly seems reasonable.

Comment: How can I check indexes for single table?

Comment: How can I upload data from file?

Comment: How can I rename a column name?